# how to change relative layout border color?

Tags: android

how to change relative layout border color??  this is my code below i just want to show border color black  but is show all relative layout black. i just want to show relative layout white color only borde will be black what  will i do??

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border5">
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item> 
         <shape android:shape="rectangle">
              <solid android:color="#000000" /> 
         </shape>
     </item>   
     <item android:left="1dp"  android:top="1dp" android:bottom="2dp" >  
         <shape android:shape="rectangle"> 
         </shape>
      </item>    
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is how I give mine a white `background` and orange border

```
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="@drawable/white" />

    <stroke
        android:width="3px"
        android:color="@drawable/orange" />

   </shape>
```

If you simply just want a border then you can keep it all in the same `<shape>` and use `<solid...>` for the `background` color (if you want to give it one) and `<stroke...>` for the border.

You can do it how you have it just change the `<solid>` to the `background` color you want and add the `<stroke>` with black

Comment: Hy, It's better use dp instead of  px