# Cannot align Imageview below another Imageview

Tags: android, android-layout

**This is what I am require to do**(The menu):

[image]

and this is what I have achieved so far:

[image]

Please see the horizontal line below an image within the list.I cannot make my screen-shot similar to the requirement.

Code:

**popupmenurow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll_menu_row_cont"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgmenuicon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"//this is the image icon
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />

    <ImageView//this is the horizontal line
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:id="@+id/horizontalline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgmenuicon"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgmenuicon"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgmenuicon"
        android:background="#4d4b56" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:id="@+id/verticalline"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:background="#4d4b56" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvmenutitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="@color/menutextcolor"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and here is the list **popup_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slide"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@null"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**What shall I do to make the horizontal line below the imageview,similar to that of my requirement(The image on the top)?**

If I remove

```
 android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgmenuicon"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgmenuicon"
```

then the line is not showing up.Also I understand that the margins occuring to the left and right of the horizontal line is due to `android:layout_margin="10dp"` within the imageview.But I cannot find a solution.

**ANSWER**

Thank you all for your precious time.Finally I have solved the problem.The solution of M090009 was close but I couldn't make it.Finally thanks to Vijay for giving me the idea about the background.

What I have done is to cut an image like this:

[image] 
 and set that image as the background of the relative layout within which my menu-icons resides.

Here is the full code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll_menu_row_cont"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"

    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_image"
       android:background="@drawable/line_box"
       android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgmenuicon"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@null"

            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"           
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />

        <!-- <View
            android:id="@+id/horizontalline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgmenuicon"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgmenuicon"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imgmenuicon"
            android:background="#4d4b56"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@null" /> -->
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/verticalline"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:background="#4d4b56"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvmenutitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="@color/menutextcolor"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Downvoters can leave a comment

Comment: please clearly state what you want to achieve?

Comment: Please read the question properly.I guess I have explained clear enough

Comment: Did you try to give border colour for `ImageView` Relative layout?

Comment: No...how to do that?

Comment: Try like this(http://stackoverflow.com/a/17980889/3564344) to give border colour. But I am not sure this is solution for your problem..

Answer (score 1):

Well you can remove the margin on the icon image and set its `scaleType` to center_corp as follows

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgmenuicon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"//this is the image icon
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="center_corp"/>
```

Comment: actually i think that **centerInside** is the best one you can checkout different scale types here http://www.techrepublic.com/article/clear-up-ambiguity-about-android-image-view-scale-types-with-this-guide/

Answer (score 1):

If the above solutions not working mean then try this. Because all the solutions are good.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll_menu_row_cont"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="@drawable/bordercolor" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgmenuicon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@null" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.75" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvmenutitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Remove the Imageview** for that divider and add this:

```
<View
     android:id="@+id/divider"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="1dp"
     android:layout_below="@+id/static_account"
     android:background="@color/divider"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change imgmenuicon's attr:

`android:layout_margin="10dp"`

to

`android:padding="10dp"`

BTW, the line should use `<View ... android:background.../>` instead of `<ImmageView ... />`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ll_menu_row_cont"
android:layout_width="270dp"
android:layout_height="78dp"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:id="@+id/rl_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgmenuicon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame"
    android:contentDescription="@null" />

    <View
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:id="@+id/horizontalline"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/imgmenuicon"
    android:background="#000" />



<View
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:id="@+id/verticalline"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/horizontalline"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#4d4b56" />


</RelativeLayout>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvmenutitle"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"

    android:text="Hello"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Try this and let me know!!!:D

Comment: please make adjustments to fit your need! or let me know i will do that for you!

Comment: I will  try this.Thank you for your reply.But I cannot get why  android:layout_width="100dp"??

Comment: i simple made that horizontal line 100 dp wide and i presumed that your images might be taking 100dp of space, i could have made it more dynamic but this will also work for now!

Comment: hello @uzair.sorry for late reply.I didny try your approach.Please see the answer I have posted.Thank you for your time.